# How to categorically characterize the structure of all grounded first-order logic formulas?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

If the notion of topos corresponds to set theory or first-order logic, then what if one is only interested in *grounded* logic formulas, ie, formulas that don't contain variables?

In a topos one has the ability to interpret logic formulas with variables, and universal and existential quantifications, etc.  But I don't need such features.  Can I use a "simpler" category instead of a topos?

Comment: The internal language of an elementary topos is an intuitionistic higher-order logic. This can more or less be identified with an intuitionistic structural set theory. If you don't care about formulas with variables, then presumably you are using something like propositional logic. In that case, you can definitely use way simpler categories, e.g. cartesian closed categories. See [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic#kinds_of_internal_logics_in_different_categories) and the pages it references for an encyclopedic overview.

Comment: Yes, but propositional logic is different from first-order logic without variables... specifically the ability to construct first-order terms...

Comment: Just make an atomic proposition for every (ground) formula you want. You'll end up with an (countably) infinite number of atomic propositions, but that isn't usually seen as too much of a problem.

Comment: I was looking for more like those "structures" in model theory, which logic theories are modeling...